# Optimizing pandas apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe with two columns, and I would like to filter the values of the second column based on different thresholds that are determined by the values of the first column. Such thresholds are defined in a dictionary, whose keys are the first column values, and the dict values are the thresholds. There will be also a default value to match columns that do not have any of the specified values.

So for example:

```
thresholds_dict = {"A": 5, "B": 2, "C": 4, "default": 0}

sample_dataframe = 
| Column1 | Column2 |
|   A     | 3       |
|   A     | 6       |
|   B     | 4       |
|   B     | 1       |
|   C     | 2       |
|   D     | 0       |

result_dataframe =
| Column1 | Column2 |
|   A     | 6       |
|   B     | 4       |
|   D     | 0       |
```

I have been doing the following to achieve this:

```
default = thresholds_dict["default"]
df[df.apply(lambda x: x["Column2"] >= thresholds_dict.get(x["Column1"], default), axis=1)]
```

However, execution time has been increased x1000 vs an implementation that just filters all DF with a single threshold. Is there any better way to implement this that avoids the apply function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), if no match get missing values, so replace it by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
thresholds_dict = {"A": 5, "B": 2, "C": 4, "default": 0}

default = thresholds_dict["default"]
df = df[df["Column2"] >= df["Column1"].map(thresholds_dict).fillna(default)]
print (df)
  Column1  Column2
1       A        6
2       B        4
5       D        0
```